# How to acces a id instead of a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selector

I've following HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="#report_question_issue"/>
```

How to access it using the following id?

```
#report_question_issue
```

If I use class insted I'm able to access this submit button but when I tried with id it's not working. How to access it by means of id?

```
$(document).on('click', '.report_question_issue', function (e) {}
```

Comment: And you only use that ID once right, not the same ID for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#` as id is accessed through `#` .Change your  html to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue"/>
```

Access using:

```
$(document).on('click', '#report_question_issue', function (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change `HTML` in this way:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue"/>
```

You don't need the `#` `HTML id` attribute.

Then you can modify your script in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#report_question_issue', function (e) {}
```

You can also use document [getElementbyId](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

```
document.getElementById("report_question_issue")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the escape character to use this id

```
$(document).on('click', '#\#report_question_issue', function (e) {}
```